# Copying a file from a remote server to local host via connection tunneling

Tags: ssh, scp, forwarding

I'm trying to copy a file from a server behind another server. Currently I'm using WinSCP in Windows in a Virtual Drive but it's super slow and I'd like to download the files onto my mac using terminal. I need to do a "forwarded connection".

So in terminal, using .ssh/config I log onto the first server:

```
ssh jump.serverexample.com
```

via port 22 using a username and password. This info I've saved in .ssh/config as so:

```
HostName jump.serverexample.com 
    Port 22  
    User user1
```

I then log into the second server behind this one using ProxyCommand having put the info into .shh/config:

```
Host hal.serverexample.com
    ProxyCommand ssh jump.serverexample.com exec -W %h %p
    Port 22
    User user1
```

This all works fine and I'm into the hal computer. using CD I can navigate and see the file. I then try to get the file back to the folder 'sharing' on my macbook's desktop using this scp command:

> scp -P 22 user1@hal.serverexample.com:folder1/folder2/folder3/file.txt /Users/user2/Desktop/sharing

It asks for my password (to the server), I put it in and then it prints:

> /Users/user2/Desktop/sharing: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? My username on the servers is different to the username on my macbook.

Comment: You're running scp on your local mac? The error message just says that the directory `/Users/user2/Desktop/sharing` doesn't exist on the local system (whatever host you're running scp on).

Comment: The destination folder exists on the MacBook.

I’ve tried initiating the SCP command to retrieve the file when logged into hal.serverexample.com. 

I’ve also tried calling the SCP command after entering the first server via ssh (jump.serverexample.com). However, this also has the same outcome.

Could it be a firewall on my router stopping the sending the file back? Or do I need to specify my username and IP address prior to the local location information in the SCP command?

Comment: "Could it be a firewall on my router stopping the sending the file back?" No. What host are you running scp on when you get this error?

Comment: When you type in the scp command and hit return, which computer (of the three) is actually running the scp program?

Comment: I've tried *jump* and *hal* as the computers running the *SCP* command.

Comment: Could it be that my ProxyCommand is asking for the files to be transferred back to the Jump server and not to my local host?